# Rotate Kubernetes Certificates with Rancher 2.1.7

Tags: kubernetes, certificate, rancher

How to rotate the certificates of a K8s cluster when Rancher version does not provide this option? I have Rancher 2.1.7 and I don't find anything about that. Do you know an API or command line doing the job?

I tried API with action=rotateCertificates but it returns InvalidAction.
I can't update Rancher.

Answer (score 1):

It looks very clear  on how to do it on the [docs](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/cluster-admin/certificate-rotation/#certificate-rotation-in-rancher-v2-1-x-and-v2-0-x):

> Available as of v2.0.14 and v2.1.9
>
> Rancher launched Kubernetes clusters have the ability to rotate the
> auto-generated certificates through the API.
>
> 1. In the Global view, navigate to the cluster that you want to rotate
>    certificates.
> 2. Select the ⋮ > View in API.
> 3. Click on RotateCertificates.
> 4. Click on Show Request.
> 5. Click on Send Request.

✌️☮️

Comment: No, this procedure works from version 2.0.14 for 2.0 branch and 2.1.9 for 2.1 branch. It does not exist for 2.1.7, here is my problem. It's not in UI. I tried to call the same api anyway but I got InvalidAction. This action is not available in this version of Rancher and I look for another way to rotate because I can't update right now

Comment: Isn't 2.1.7 for 2.1 branch? maybe the recommendation from Rancher is just to upgrade to 2.1.9